# Using Through to evaluate complex expressions

Tags: functional-style, pure-function

Suppose we're given the expression `f*g+h`, where `f,g,h` are all pure functions. How can we evaluate this expression on some `x`? If there were only one operation, say `f+g`, we could simply use `Through[(f+g)[x]]`, but `Through` only deals with one operation, as far as I can see. How is this done?

Comment: To clarify, you are asking for through to apply the pure functions at the most nested level to `x`? Your example is `Plus[Times[f,g],h]`, so the functions you want applied to x are `Level[f*g + h, {-1}]`?

Comment: `Apply[(f[##] g[##] + h[##]) &, {arguments}]`, crude version of what Mr. Wizard have showed.

Comment: Ah, yes, that is what I want @VF1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Edit:**

Mr.Wizard helped to refine my old function to:

```
SetAttributes[Through2, HoldFirst]
Through2[head_[args___]] := Replace[head, s : _Function | _Symbol :> s[args], -1]
```

This locates the most nested functions and symbols and evaluates their value for the parameter arguments.

**Below is my older, less robust function:**

```
SetAttributes[Through2, HoldFirst]
Through2[expr_] := 
 With[{head = Head@expr, arg = First@expr}, 
  With[{funcs = Cases[head, _Function | _Symbol, -1]}, 
   head /. Thread[funcs -> Through[funcs[arg]]]]]
Through2[(f*g + h)[x]]
(* f[x] g[x] + h[x] *)
Through2[(f*g + (h*Minus)^2)[x]]
(* f[x] g[x] + x^2 h[x]^2 *)
Through2[{Re, Im + Re}[x]]
(* {Re[x], Im[x] + Re[x]} *)
```

Comment: Interesting interpretation. +1  I still wonder what the OP actually wants however.

Comment: This works great, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps you want something like this?

```
apply = (# /. s_Symbol /; Context[s] =!= "System`" :> s[##2]) &;

apply[f*g + h, x]
```

> ```
> f[x] g[x] + h[x]
> ```

This is a limited implementation but it can be extended if this is in fact the kind of operation you desire.  The idea is to recognize any Symbol not belonging to the `` System` ``  context as a function to apply to `x`.  Alternatively one could apply only symbols in the `` Global` `` context using `` Context[s] === "Global`" ``.

Comment: Yes, I'd say that our functions do the same thing (with yours being more elegant and direct). In hindsight, `Cases` and then `ReplaceAll` does seem a bit redundant - and dangerous, too, if one of the pure functions is used on a higher level in the expression. Your solution will be more robust.

Comment: @VF1 Thanks for the check.  If you'd like to put this in your answer instead that's fine with me; it was your idea to look at the levelspec.

Comment: Will do. Thanks.

Comment: @VF1 It just occurred to me that my `{-1}` code is broken for `Function` as that will not be found at level `{-1}`; Please use the `Heads -> False` code, assuming that isn't broken.

Comment: Is there a difference between Yours `apply` and @VF1 's `Through2` exept that the latter works for 1 argument only (after edit it works for many) and Yours can not handle `Minus` and other `System` context functions?

Comment: `Heads->False` didn't work either on examples such as `Through2[{#1 &, Im}[x]]`, unfortunately, as `Function` is a head. However, using the "relative" level of `-1` instead of `{-1}` seems to be a fix.

Comment: @Kuba Indeed, but as Mr.Wizard mentions in his answer, the context can be changed.

Comment: @VF1 "Indeed" implies "there is a difference" other than those I've mentioned. Sorry for catching the words but I want to be sure :)

Comment: @VF1 I was not thinking very well; of course `Heads -> False` is the default for `Replace`.  By the way I meant use the version with `-1` rather than `{-1}`, just as you did.  I'm now deleting that section of my answer.

Comment: @Kuba Referring to the code presently in both answers, they are entirely different approaches.  Mine works based on the idea that active functions can be referenced by context, whereas VF1's method works by recognizing any Symbol (or `Function`) that does not itself have arguments.  Arguably both are useful.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I have asked a vague question, I know that aproaches differ. I meant, are there others differences in effect/application of those two?

Answer (score 0):

For example...

```
f=#&;
g=2#^2&;
h=-Sqrt[#]&;
```

Using substitution rule...

```
f*g+h /. z:(f|g|h)->z[3]
```

Gives...

```
54-Sqrt[3]
```