# Replace custom functions, leave built in functions untouched?

Tags: replacement

I have three expressions `a[x, y], b[x, y], c[x, y]` that act as placeholders for functions of two variables `x,y`. Consider the following substitution:

```
a[x, y]/(b[x, y] c[x, y]) /. f_[x1_, y1_] :> f[2 x1, 3 y1]
```

> `a[2 x, 3 y]/(64 b[x, y]^3 c[x, y]^3)`

In the output we see that the numerator expression was substituted properly, but in the denominator the pattern `f_` registered for the head `Power` instead of looking for my own expressions. Of course I can fix this by:

```
a[x, y]/(b[x, y] c[x, y]) /. a[x1_, y1_] :> a[2 x1, 3 y1] /.b[x1_, y1_] :> b[2 x1, 3 y1] /. c[x1_, y1_] :> c[2 x1, 3 y1]
```

> `a[2 x, 3 y]/(b[2 x, 3 y] c[2 x, 3 y])`

which gives the desired output. But this amounts to writing three times as many substitution directives and is therefore inconvenient. To fix the first example, I tried using `/. f_Symbol[x1_, y1_] :> f[2 x1, 3 y1]` or `/. f_[x1_, y1_]/;Head[f]===Symbol :> f[2 x1, 3 y1]`, but this does not correct it. Is there a way to write a proper substitution that works with headers and does not act on built in functions? Thanks for any suggestions.

EDIT:

Just noticed that `Head[Power]` actually returns `Symbol`, which is kind of weird. I would have expected it to return e.g. `Function`, or `Directive`, or something along the lines. (If one unprotects and clears the `Power` function, then I would again expect `Head[Power]` to return `Symbol` of course. But maybe that's just me...)

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but if you want to match a defined set of functions without writing a rule for each, you could replace `f_` by `(f:(a|b|c))`

Comment: `Product` is not a head that ever appears in these expressions. This can be seen by using `FullForm` or `FreeQ[a[x, y]/(b[x, y] c[x, y]), Product]`. It is a little bit tricky to see what heads `f_` will be matched with, as things depend on evaluation, but the heads are `a`, `Power` and `Power`. This can be seen from `Reap[a[x, y]/(b[x, y] c[x, y]) /. f_[x1_, y1_] :> Sow[f]][[2, 1]]` .

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom Thank you for pointing that out! I updated the question to properly refer to `Power` head instead of `Product`. (The problem stays the same though.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The best method I am aware of to handle this kind of problem is to filter by *context*.<sup>[(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28058/121)</sup>

```
SetAttributes[user, HoldFirst]
user[s_Symbol] := Context@Unevaluated@s =!= "System`";

a[x, y]/(b[x, y] c[x, y]) /. f_?user[x1_, y1_] :> f[2 x1, 3 y1]
```

> ```
> a[2 x, 3 y]/(b[2 x, 3 y] c[2 x, 3 y])
> ```

One could include other contexts in the exclusion besides System, or use the inverse and test only for user symbols existing in the `` "Global`" `` context.  Without additional examples my example is as specific as I can make it.

---

Regarding the unusual evaluation of the `?` operator ([`PatternTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html)) please see:

- [Why doesn't PatternTest work with Composition?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1699/121)

Comment: Worth to stress out that `f_?user[x1_, y1_]` works like `(f_?user)[x1_, y1_]`. Or maybe it is just me who was surprised when have faced that for the first time :)

Comment: @Kuba I needed a second look as well; though I'm no *expert* in any case.

Comment: It occurs to me that this will not work for functions from included in [Wolfram System Standard Extra Packages](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/StandardExtraPackages.html) that have not yet been rolled into the ``System` `` context.

Comment: @Edmund Yes, you can modify it with `MemberQ` but there is no clear distinction between Standard Extra Package and a custom one.

Comment: @Kuba Good point; link added.

Answer (score 13):

You can impose conditions on the patterns to restrict their matching:

```
a[x, y]/(b[x, y] c[x, y]) /. 
 f_?(MemberQ[{a, b, c}, #] &)[x1_, y1_] :> f[2 x1, 3 y1]
```

or the alternative, equivalent:

```
a[x, y]/(b[x, y] c[x, y]) /. 
 f_[x1_, y1_] :> f[2 x1, 3 y1] /; MemberQ[{a, b, c}, f]
```

Both expressions return your desired result:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 12):

Because built-in functions are `Protected`, the following also works.

```
a[x, y]/(b[x, y] c[x, y]) /. 
    f_[x1_, y1_] :> f[2 x1, 3 y1] /; ! MemberQ[Attributes[f], Protected]

(* a[2 x, 3 y]/(b[2 x, 3 y] c[2 x, 3 y]) *)
```

Comment: Every symbol can be protected.

Comment: Unless it is already `Locked` :)

Comment: @Kuba  What you say is true.  Good comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the feature that all built-in functions start with capital letters.
if you maintain your user functions start with lowercase letters you can do this:

```
SetAttributes[user, HoldFirst] 
user[s_Symbol] := Capitalize[ToString[s]] =!= ToString[s]; 
a[x, y]/(b[x, y] c[x, y]) /. f_?user[x1_, y1_] :> f[2 x1, 3 y1]

a[2 x, 3 y]/(b[2 x, 3 y] c[2 x, 3 y])
```