# Problem with defining a simple linear operator

Tags: variable-definitions, operators

I need to define a linear operator, which should have very simple linearity:

```
myOp[Plus[f_, g_]] := myOp[f] + myOp[g]
myOp[a_ f_[x_, t_]] := a myOp[f[x, t]]
```

where `f` and `g` are considered functions of `x` and `t`, while `a` is a constant.

Testing

```
myOp[c h1[x, t] + c^2 h2[x, t]]
```

> `c myOp[h1[x,t]]+h2[x,t] myOp[c^2]`

The first term behaves good, but why the second term has been given in this form? It is expected to give

> `c myOp[h1[x, t]]+c^2 myOp[h2[x, t]]`

That is, `myOp` should only act on the function.

Any suggestions are welcome. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simpler case `myOp[c^2 h2[x, t]]` has a similar problem using your current definitions:

```
myOp[c^2 h2[x, t]]
```

> `h2[x, t] myOp[c^2]`

If you look at the `FullForm` of `c^2`, you will notice it expressed as `Power[c, 2]`. This means that the expression `myOp[c^2 h2[x, t]` really corresponds to `myOp[Times[Power[c, 2], h2[x, t]]]`. This matches your second definition of `myOp`, but between the `Power` and `h2` expressions, which should be assigned to `a`, and which should be assigned to `h` in your definition pattern? The "wrong" choice of assignments is what leads to your unwanted result.

---

Instead, you may want to consider any expression with a built-in head (such as  `Power`) as "constants" in your definition. You can filter those out by the context in which those symbols reside. In fact, built-in functions reside in the `` System` `` context, whereas most of your user-defined ones will reside e.g. in the `` Global` `` context.

[Following Mr. Wizard's lead](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/131941/27951) from a previous question, we can implement a helper function to distinguish them in your definition:

```
ClearAll[isBuiltIn]
isBuiltIn[s_] := Context[Evaluate@Head@s] === "System`"
```

For instance: `isBuiltIn[c^2]` returns `True`.

So now we modify your definitions:

```
ClearAll[myOp]
myOp[Plus[f_, g_]] := myOp[f] + myOp[g]
myOp[a_?isBuiltIn f_[x_, t_]] := a myOp[f[x, t]]
```

and try this out:

```
myOp[c^2 h2[x, t]]
```

> `c^2 myOp[h2[x, t]]`

and for your original case:

```
myOp[c h1[x, t] + c^2 h2[x, t]]
```

> `c myOp[h1[x, t]] + c^2 myOp[h2[x, t]]`

Comment: Thanks. The answer resolved the problem well. But for a slight extended (my real problem including `D` on a function), `myOp[D[u0[x,t]+c u1[x,t]+c^2 u2[x,t],x]]`, it gives a looking-correct answer with a warning >Context::ssle: "Symbol, string, or HoldPattern[symbol] expected at position 1 in Context[...]" Any idea?

Comment: What about `myOp[c h1[x, t] h2[x, t]]`? I expect `c myOp[h1[x, t] h2[x, t]]` but it gives `c h2[x, t] myOp[h1[x, t]]`.