# Creating a pure function that does operations with pure functions

Tags: functions, function-construction, pure-function

Suppose I have two functions defined as follows:

```
a = #+3&
b = #^2 + 3&
```

So 
when I call `a[2]` and `b[1]` the output is exactly what I would expect.

```
a[2]
5
b[1]
4
```

Now I want to create another function let's call it `c` that is the sum of the functions `a` and `b`.

How do I do that?

Comment: `c = a[#] + b[#]&`

Comment: @Kuba that is the obvious solution, but in my code `a` and `b` are being created in different parts, and when I create `a ` I have no idea what `b` is going to be.

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood, a moment. It worked. Fantastic thank you.

Comment: Related: [(28056)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28056/121)

Comment: I am still trying to figure out why `b[1] = 1` :|

Comment: @polfosol it was a typo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Haven't found a duplicate nor it is rtfm question so I will leave this cw answer:

```
c = a[#] + b[#]&
```

which should be clear but feel free to ask otherwise.

Answer (score 8):

For simple expressions like a sum, there is [`Through`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Through.html).  The following kind of use is shown in the docs:

```
a[3] + b[3]
Through[(a + b)[3]]
(*
  18
  18
*)
```

It works for simple homogeneous expressions like `a + b` or `a * b`, in which all the elements of level 1 are functions.
To get a function as a result instead of a value, one can use `#` and `&` instead of `3` as shown below.  One might use [`Evaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html) to evaluate the body. Beware that symbolic parameters would have their values substituted, if any, when `Evaluate` is used.  One can see from the output below that the unevaluated construction still depends on the definitions of `a` and `b`, and in the evaluated construction, we have a definite function that does not depend on any external values or definitions.  One should consider which is most appropriate in a given use case.

```
c = Through[(a + b)[#]] &
c = Evaluate@Through[(a + b)[#]] &
(*
  Through[(a + b)[#1]] &
  6 + #1 + #1^2 &
*)
```

Sometimes it happens that a more complicated combination of functions is desired.  Let's say the expression has been generated programmatically, either in the symbolic form `1 + 5 x + y^2` or more awkwardly in the form `1 + 5 a + b^2`, with the [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) expressions substituted

```
1 + 5 a + b^2
(*  1 + 5 (#1 + 3 &) + (#1^2 + 3 &)^2  *)
```

Then [`ReplaceAll` (`/.`)](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html)
will be your friend.  Again the same advantages and disadvantages of `Evaluate` should be considered.

```
1 + 5 a + b^2 /. {a -> a[3], b -> b[3]}
(*  175  *)

c = 1 + 5 a + b^2 /. {a -> a[#], b -> b[#]} &
c = Evaluate[1 + 5 a + b^2 /. {a -> a[#], b -> b[#]}] &
(*
  1 + 5 a + b^2 /. {a -> a[#1], b -> b[#1]} &
  1 + 5 (3 + #1) + (3 + #1^2)^2 &
*)
```

Here's a simple function that operates somewhat like `Through` on a functional expression `(expr)[x]`. A second argument specifies the functions to be replaced in the operation.  They can be rules that substitute a function for a symbol.  if it is `Automatic`, the expressions in `Variables[expr]` are treated as functions.  (I was surprised `Automatic` works for expressions in terms of the OP's `a` and `b`, which are pure functions.)

```
plugin[expr_[x___], fns_: Automatic] := 
  expr /. Replace[
    Flatten[{fns} /. Automatic :> Variables[expr]], (* construct replacements:          *)
    {HoldPattern[f_ -> g_] :> f :> g[x],            (*   rule for f:  f :> plug into g  *)
     f_ :> f :> f[x]},                              (*   function f:  f :> plug into f  *)
    1];
```

Examples:

```
plugin[(1 + 5 a + b^2)[3]]                                (* Automatic substitution *)
(*  175  *)

Evaluate@plugin[(1 + 5 a + b^2)[#]] &                     (* Automatic substitution *)
(*  1 + 5 (3 + #1) + (3 + #1^2)^2 &  *)

Evaluate@plugin[(1 + 5 a + b^2)[#], {a, b}] &             (* Specified functions *)
(*  1 + 5 (3 + #1) + (3 + #1^2)^2 &  *)

Evaluate@plugin[(1 + 5 x + y^2)[#], {x -> a, y -> b}] &   (* Substitution via rules *)
(*  1 + 5 (3 + #1) + (3 + #1^2)^2 &  *)

Simplify@plugin[(x^2 + y^2)[t], {x -> Cos, y -> Sin}]
(*  1   *)

plugin[(x^2 - 3 y^2 + z)[u, v]]
(*  x[u, v]^2 - 3 y[u, v]^2 + z[u, v]  *)
```